# Can we add a customised message to the below telling invalid dates and make the table disappear if end date is before start date

Tags: r, shiny

Can we add a customized message to the below telling invalid dates and make the table disappear if end date is before start date . Right now it is showing only invalid dates and table still appears. Can we achieve this? Please help me in solving this. I tried to add `req` as well to the code base but not working

server.R

```
source("df.R")
library(dplyr)

server <- function(input, output,session) { 
  df1 <- df %>% filter(Date1 == Sys.Date())
  data_1 <- reactiveVal(df1)



observeEvent(input$Submit,{
  req(input$Date[[1]] <= input$Date[[2]])
  if (input$Tic == "ALL"){
    table_display <- df %>% filter(Date1 %in% input$Date[1] : input$Date[2])
  }

  else if (input$Tic == "ALL" && input$Date[1] == Sys.Date() && input$Date[2] == Sys.Date())
   { 
    table_display <- df %>% filter(Date1 == Sys.Date())
   }

  else if (input$Tic != "ALL" && input$Date[1] == Sys.Date() && input$Date[2] == Sys.Date())
  {
    table_display <- df %>% filter(ID %in% input$Tic & Date1 == Sys.Date())
  }

 else 
  {
    table_display <- df %>% filter(ID %in% input$Tic & Date1 %in% input$Date[1] : input$Date[2])
  }

  data_1(table_display)
},ignoreNULL = FALSE)

# observeEvent(input$Submit,{
#   if (input$Date[[1]] > input$Date[[2]]) {
#     showNotification("Invalid dates")
#     }
# })


output$Inv <- renderText({
  if (input$Date[[1]] > input$Date[[2]]) {
    print("Invalid dates. Your start date is after end Date. Please select valid dates")
  }
})

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
  # #req(input$Date[[1]] <= input$Date[[2]])
  # req(isolate(input$Date[[1]]) <= isolate(input$Date[[2]]))

  datatable(data_1())
})

}
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)
source("df.R")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(".shiny-output-error{visibility: hidden;}")),
    dateRangeInput("Date", "", start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date(), format = "yyyy-mm-dd", separator = "-"),
    selectInput("Tic","",choices = c("ALL",as.character(df$ID)),selected = "ALL"),
    actionButton("Submit","Submit"),
    textOutput("Inv"),
    dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)
```

df.R

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1541662915.921, 1541562949.500, 
                                         1581145671.845, 1581145671.845, 1541662993.957, 1541662915.921, 
                                        1541662949.842, 1541662949.845, 1541662949.845, 1581145671.957
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date1 = structure(c(17843, 
                                                                       17843, 17844, 17843, 18843, 17843, 18300, 17843, 17843, 18300
), class = "Date"), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AAA", "BBB"), class = "factor"), 
Value = c(68, 70175, 71107, 702175, 72638, 7238, 739, 738469, 
          75901, 7106), Status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Approved", "Pending"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                   -10L), class = "data.frame")
df$Date <- NULL
df$Status <- NULL
```

Comment: Try to add `req(input$Date[[1]] > input$Date[[2]])` just before `datatable(data_1())`

Comment: Thanks will check. But may I know why req is used??? I mean the logic

Comment: See the documentation (`?req`). `req` means "require".

Comment: I tried but it is not working :(

Comment: Sorry this is the converse: `req(input$Date[[1]] <= input$Date[[2]])`.

Comment: Perfect and it is working . But actually the table is disappearing before pressing the button itself. I was trying to make it disappear after clicking action button so that I can see the message "Invalid Dates". Can we add this feature? I have edited my code for you

Comment: Hi Stephane. I some how managed to achieve this partially. I have edited my code. Now when the dates are invalid it appears on the screen that is good. But once the user changes the date (proper format), without clicking the submit button the table appears. You can run my code and you may get an idea. Only Thing is after clicking the submit button, the table should appear. Also when the user changes the date, the table flickers without clicking submit button. Can we remove this feature?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you try `req(isolate(input$Date[[1]]) <= isolate(input$Date[[2]]))`.

Comment: I tried with isolate before actually. But actually some minor issue is going on. If you closely observe the application. LIke open the application > Select start date as Feb 27, 2020 > Select AAA/BBB > Submit > Table Disappears . And the table will not appear even if select proper dates in future. Make sense? I have edited my code for you

Comment: But do you want the table to disappear if the dates are not valid, before pressing the Submit button ? And actually what is the interest of the Submit button?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the behavior you are expecting. Is it what you want:

```
server <- function(input, output,session) { 

  dtable <- eventReactive(input$Submit, {
    req(input$Date[[1]] <= input$Date[[2]])
    if (input$Tic == "ALL") {
      df %>% filter(Date1 %in% input$Date[1] : input$Date[2])
    } else if (input$Tic == "ALL" && input$Date[1] == Sys.Date() && 
               input$Date[2] == Sys.Date()) { 
      df %>% filter(Date1 == Sys.Date())
    } else if (input$Tic != "ALL" && input$Date[1] == Sys.Date() && 
               input$Date[2] == Sys.Date()) {
      df %>% filter(ID %in% input$Tic & Date1 == Sys.Date())
    } else {
      df %>% filter(ID %in% input$Tic & Date1 %in% input$Date[1] : input$Date[2])
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$Inv <- renderText({
    if (input$Date[[1]] > input$Date[[2]]) {
      print("Invalid dates")
    }
  })

  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(dtable())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. Your helped me actually. But you removed some of my code that I require it :) I took a portion of your code to mine and it is working. But actually, if invalid dates are selected the table is not disappearing and only message pops up. I have edited my code for you,If the table disappears then all good . Really thanks for the help

Comment: @imranp So you want the table to disappear whenever invalid dates are selected, without pressing the Submit button?

Comment: Yes it should disappear after **clicking submit button** and also message pops ups telling invalid date. Then later if the user selects any filters and valid dates and press submit button the table should appear accordingly. Hope this make more sense.

Comment: @imranp So I thought this is what I did. Can you give me a scenario which does not provide the expected behavior with my code?

Comment: Sure. Let’s say. Scenario 1 : The user opens the app > selects any filter > selects valid dates> press submit button> now table appears accordingly that is good. Scenario 2 : The user opens the app > selects any filters > select invalid dates > press submit button > now the table should disappear and message should pop up telling invalid dates. Scenario 3 : Now If the user follows scenario 1 , the table should appear accordingly as usual

Comment: When I perform scenario 2 your code doesn’t disappear the table  but only message pops up

Comment: @imranp For me, scenario 2 works as expected. The table disappears. Are you sure you have correctly copied my code ?

Comment: For me it is not. Yes I have copied me You can see my edited question server. R